# C Thread safe locale/encoding when using sprintf and printf

Tags: c, multithreading, encoding, printf, locale

This question is not related to something that i want to do at the moment, but something i wondered while reading the (GNU/Linux/ISO-C) Documentation for `sprintf()` `printf()` and `setlocale()`.

The hypothetical problem:

Imagine a **multithreaded** application which uses **printf/scanf** family for user faced text output on one thread and printf/scanf for file or even network I/O on **another thread**. Now imagine a scenario where that application needs to use **different encodings/locales** for the different kinds of I/O.
The way to set the locale/encoding is to use `setlocale()` which is explicitly marked as "MT-Unsafe" int the [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html).

ISO/IEC 9899:2018 has the following to say at 7.11.1.1

> A call to the setlocale function may introduce a data race with other calls to the setlocale
>   function or with calls to functions that are affected by the current locale. The implementation shall
>   behave as if no library function calls the setlocale function.

As far as i see it, this leaves standard C with no standard way to handle the situation described prior. (that does not involve needless synchronization between threads that otherwise don't neccesairily interfere)

Note that POSIX specifies the [`uselocale()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uselocale.html) function which is specifically made for this.
But this is no solution for i.e. embedded or tuly multi-platform code.

**The question(s)**:

- is there a portable, not cumbersome way to handle these kinds of situations without resorting to custom libaries
- if not so: what might be the reason to ommit such capability from the standard

TL;DR:
How to handle multithreaded encoding (outside POSIX)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot safely use `setlocale` at all in a program once it becomes multithreaded. If you need multiple locales, you need the `newlocale`/`uselocale` API for thread-local or first-class locale objects, not `setlocale`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using more or less standard mutexes? E.g. as explained at [How to Use C Mutex Lock Examples for Linux Thread Synchronization](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/):

**Introduction**

We employ `pthread.h`. The thread management would be then:

```
...
pthread_t tid[2];
pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
...
```

A mutex is initialized and then a lock is achieved by calling the following two functions:

```
int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex, const pthread_mutexattr_t *restrict attr);
int pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

The mutex can be unlocked and destroyed by calling following functions:

```
int pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
int pthread_mutex_destroy(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

**Practical Example**

Lets see a piece of code where mutexes are used for thread synchronization:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t tid[2];
int counter;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    unsigned long i = 0;
    counter += 1;
    printf("\n Job %d started\n", counter);

    for(i=0; i<(0xFFFFFFFF);i++);

    printf("\n Job %d finished\n", counter);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(i < 2)
    {
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        i++;
    }

    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```